# Xcode 11.1 not showing up in my applications folder

Tags: macos, xcode, macos-mojave

I recently reinstalled Xcode, My current version of the Xcode is Version 11.1 (11A1027)

After the install, I cannot see it in my Applications folder. I have it my Dock, i have it in my Launcher, but not the application folder.

I am currently on macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6

Any troubleshooting or any suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's showing up in your Dock, you should be able to find it by clicking-and-holding on it in the Dock; that should open a pop-up menu, from which you can choose Options > Show in Finder.